# Как открыть документы PDF без скачивания на android?

Tags: android, pdf, webview, app

Раньше юзал apple, импортозаместил на android. Всё нравится, но единственное напрягает просмотр PDF документов, например в приложение mail, нужно сначала скачать, только потом можно посмотреть. Ребята из тех. поддержки майл ответили так: 
**"Вложения открываются с помощью сторонних приложений, предустановленных в системе.
Найдите подходящее формату файла приложение в магазине Google Play и загрузите его на ваше устройство."**
Как я понимаю на apple всё это как то работает через web. Может и на андроид можно сделать как то по умолчанию?

Comment: А что вы от нас-то хотите? Вам правильно ответили - найдите подходящее вашему вкусу приложение. Если вы хотите видеть содержимое PDF прямо в письме - ищите почтовый клиент, который это поддерживает. Если устроит в отдельном окне по клику на вложение - ищите просмотрщик соответствующих документов или целый офис. В любом случае здесь это оффтоп, если вы не собираетесь всё это разрабатывать самостоятельно.

Comment: Максимум что я хотел услышать от вас это варианты, один из которых ваш - почтовый клиент. Установка доп. приложений для чтения PDF ничего не давало, к сожалению, о чем забыл написать в тексте проблемы.

Comment: В iOS Safari является по сути системным приложением и имеет встроенный просмотрщик PDF. В Android же для просмотра PDF браузера недостаточно. Google Drive к примеру имеет встроенный просмотрщик PDF.